# Всегда ли необходимо тире?

Tags: тире

Я король! 
Должно ли в такой фразе всегда стоять тире? Какие правила это регулируют?

Comment: @Maria, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> Я король! Должно ли в такой фразе
> всегда стоять тире?

Не должно. Но может (при желании пишущего) быть и поставлено.

Answer (score 1):

```
      Какие правила это регулируют?
```

Это правило постановки тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Тире **не ставится**, если:

1. Подлежащее выражено инфинитивом, сказуемое – наречием на -о (Курить вредно).
2. Подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, сказуемое – именительным падежом существительного (Я честный человек).

НО:

1. Тире **ставится** при подлежащем, выраженным личным местоимением, и сказуемым, выраженным именительным падежом существительного:

а) при логическом подчеркивании (Я – гражданин России);

б) при структурном параллелизме предложений (Мы – люди спокойные. Он – человек беспокойный);

в) при обратном порядке слов (Герой этого спектакля – я).

Нам подходит пункт а)       ***Я - король!*** - вполне возможно, потому что здесь восклицательный знак, значит, есть логическое подчёркивание. Но при спокойной интонации тире нет.

Comment: Все правила не пишу, они в учебнике есть

Comment: Спасибо! Все очень точно и ясно)

Answer (score 1):

В приведенных примерах на эту тему не всегда есть особенная патетика и восклицательная интонации, но знаки стоят разные. Расстановка знаков препинания зависит от общей структуры предложения.

Буду дураком, утверждая, что Я ― король. 
Я ― царь, Я ― король… Они разговаривали со мной с высоты своего величия.
И все! И Я ― король! Хозяин.

Если мне это удалось ― я корОль. Я могу говорить что угодно, я корОль. Во-первых, я корОль, чем-то должен отличаться от простых пьющих, а во-вторых, сегодня праздник.

Постановка тире зависит от интонации, причем не только от пауз, но и от ударения. Обратим внимание: при постановке тире логическое ударение падает НА ПОДЛЕЖАЩЕЕ (я), а при отсутствии тире - НА СКАЗУЕМОЕ. Именно такая расстановка УДАРЕНИЯ и определяет наличие ПАУЗЫ, которая обозначается тире.

Answer (score 0):

Если местоимение логически выделяется, то да, можно поставить тире: Я - король! А так - нет, нельзя!